# How to use Preview as default pdf viewer in TeXstudio?

Tags: texstudio, viewers

I am using TeXstudio to write pdf documents with LaTeX. I want to use Preview as default pdf viewer instead of Adobe Reader.

Comment: Can you please have a look at your previous questions? Many of them have answer which seems to solve the questions, but do not have any accepted answer.

Answer (score 4):

In the preferences, replace `open`

[image]

with `open -a Preview %.pdf`